# How can I render class components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a boilerplate for a website that uses uploadProductPage.js and uploadProductPageClassComponents.js. I would like to have the site display a dropzone box so I can upload an image to amazon s3, but whenever I try to render it, it gives me the error that "onDrop" is undefined. How can I define class components in order to render it?

The code:
uploadProductPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, message, Input, Icon } from 'antd';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload'
import Axios from 'axios';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import download from './download.jpeg'



const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

 
const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "1" },
    { key: 2, value: "2" },
    { key: 3, value: "3" },
    { key: 4, value: "4" },
    { key: 5, value: "5" },
    { key: 6, value: "6" },
    { key: 7, value: "7" }
]


function UploadProductPage(props) {

    const [TitleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("")
    const [DescriptionValue, setDescriptionValue] = useState("")
    const [PriceValue, setPriceValue] = useState(0)
    const [ContinentValue, setContinentValue] = useState([])
    const [Images, setImages] = useState([])

    const onTitleChange = (event) => {
        setTitleValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setDescriptionValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onPriceChange = (event) => {
        setPriceValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const onContinentsSelectChange = (event) => {
        setContinentValue(event.currentTarget.value)
    }

    const updateImages = (newImages) => {
        setImages(newImages)
    }


    ///////// on drop stuff 

  
    const onSubmit = (event, files) => {
        event.preventDefault();


        if (!TitleValue || !DescriptionValue || !PriceValue ||
            !ContinentValue || !Images) {
            return alert('fill all the fields first!')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: props.user.userData._id,
            title: TitleValue,
            description: DescriptionValue,
            price: PriceValue,
            images: Images,
            continents: ContinentValue,
        }

        Axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('Product Successfully Uploaded')
                    props.history.push({
                        pathname: "/user/cart",
                        state: {
                          data: variables,
                        }, 
                      })
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload Product')
                }
            })
            const data = new FormData();
            if ( this.state.selectedFile ) 
           {data.append( 'profileImage', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name );
            Axios.post( '/api/profile/profile-img-upload', data, {
                headers: {
                 'accept': 'application/json',
                 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
                }
               })
                .then( ( response ) => {if ( 200 === response.status ) {
                  // If file size is larger than expected.
                  if( response.data.error ) {
                   if ( 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE' === response.data.error.code ) {
                    this.ocShowAlert( 'Max size: 2MB', 'red' );
                   } else {
                    console.log( response.data );// If not the given file type
                    this.ocShowAlert( response.data.error, 'red' );
                   }
                  } else {
                   // Success
                   let fileName = response.data;
                   console.log( 'fileName', fileName );
                   this.ocShowAlert( 'File Uploaded', '#3089cf' );
                  }
                 }
                }).catch( ( error ) => {
                // If another error
                this.ocShowAlert( error, 'red' );
               });
              } else {
               // if file not selected throw error
               this.ocShowAlert( 'Please upload file', 'red' );
              }
    }

    return (
        
        <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2}> Upload Prompt </Title>

    
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            

        </div>
            


            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} >

                {/* DropZone */}
                <Dropzone
                onDrop={this.onDrop}
                multiple={false}
                maxSize={800000000}
            >
                {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                    <div style={{
                        width: '300px', height: '240px', border: '1px solid lightgray',
                        display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}
                        {...getRootProps()}
                    >
                        {console.log('getRootProps', { ...getRootProps() })}
                        {console.log('getInputProps', { ...getInputProps() })}
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        <Icon type="plus" style={{ fontSize: '3rem' }} />

                    </div>
                )}
            </Dropzone>
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Subject</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onTitleChange}
                    value={TitleValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onDescriptionChange}
                    value={DescriptionValue}
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <label>Pages</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={onPriceChange}
                    value={PriceValue}
                    type="number"
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Due Date</label>
                <br /><br />
                <Input onChange={onContinentsSelectChange} value={ContinentValue}
                    type="date"
                />
                <br />
                <br />
                <Button
                    onClick={onSubmit}
                >
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

uploadProductPageClassComponents.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, Input } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';


const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input;

const Continents = [
    { key: 1, value: "Africa" },
    { key: 2, value: "Europe" },
    { key: 3, value: "Asia" },
    { key: 4, value: "North America" },
    { key: 5, value: "South America" },
    { key: 6, value: "Australia" },
    { key: 7, value: "Antarctica" }
]


export class UploadProductPage extends Component 
{constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
        selectedFile: null,
        selectedFiles: null
       }

     onDrop = ( event ) => {
        this.setState({
         selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
        });
  
        let formData = new FormData();
            const config = {
                header: {
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`
                }
            }
            formData.append("profileImage", files[0])
            //save the Image we chose inside the Node Server 
                      
      }

        onDelete = (image) => {
        const currentIndex = Images.indexOf(image);

        let newImages = [...Images]
        newImages.splice(currentIndex, 1)

        setImages(newImages)
        props.refreshFunction(newImages)
    }
    
    state = {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        continents: [],
        images: [],
        price: []
    }

    handleChangeTitle = (event) => {
        this.setState({ title: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    handleChangePrice = (event) => {
        this.setState({ price: parseInt(event.currentTarget.value, 10) })
    }

    handleChangeDecsription = (event) => {
        // console.log(event.currentTarget.value)
        this.setState({ description: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    handleChangeContinents = (event) => {
        this.setState({ continents: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (this.props.user.userData && !this.props.user.userData.isAuth) {
            return alert('Please Log in First')
        }

        if (!this.state.title || !this.state.description ||
            !this.state.continents || !this.state.images
            || !this.state.price) {
            return alert('Please first fill all the fields')
        }

        const variables = { 
            writer: this.props.user.userData._id,
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            images: this.state.images,
            continents: this.state.continents,
            price: this.state.price
        }

        axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('video Uploaded Successfully')
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.props.history.push('/')
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload video')
                }
            })
    }

    updateFiles = (newImages) => {
        this.setState({ images: newImages })
    }
}

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2} > Upload Prompt </Title>
            </div>
            <Dropzone
                onDrop={this.onDrop}
                multiple={false}
                maxSize={800000000}
            >
                {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
                    <div style={{
                        width: '300px', height: '240px', border: '1px solid lightgray',
                        display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}
                        {...getRootProps()}
                    >
                        {console.log('getRootProps', { ...getRootProps() })}
                        {console.log('getInputProps', { ...getInputProps() })}
                        <input {...getInputProps()} />
                        <Icon type="plus" style={{ fontSize: '3rem' }} />

                    </div>
                )}
            </Dropzone>

            <div style={{ display: 'flex', width: '300px', height: '300px'}}>

                {Images.map((image, index) => (
                    <div onClick={() => onDelete(image)}>
                        <img style={{ minWidth: '300px', width: '300px', height: '240px' }} src={download} alt={`productImg-${index}`} />
                    </div>
                ))}


            </div>

            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
               
               <FileUpload refreshFunction={this.updateFiles} />

                <br /><br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
                    value={this.state.title}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Description</label>
                <TextArea
                    onChange={this.handleChangeDecsription}
                    value={this.state.description}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Price($)</label>
                <Input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={this.handleChangePrice}
                    value={this.state.price}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <Input 
                type="date"
                onChange={this.handleChangeContinents}>
                        value={this.state.continents}
                    ))
                </Input>
                <br /><br />

                <Button type="primary" size="large" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}


export default UploadProductPage
```

Comment: Move all the functions outside of the `constructor` and open the browser debugger tools to see the errors in your code.

Comment: Which `UploadProductPage` are you trying to use? The functional component doesn't have an `onDrop` function, and if it did it's a functional component so there is no `this`, and the second snippet class-based component appears to define the function *inside* the constructor, but without `this`, so `this.onDrop` isn't defined. The second snippet also defines the component state twice.